# Accessing @api variable wrapper fields

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, wrapper-class

I am new to LWC and I have created the following wrapper:

```
public class myWrapper{
    @AuraEnabled public Object1__c object1 {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled public Object2__c object2 {get; set;}
}
```

I have passed this wrapper from a LWC to another one using:

```
<c-second-lwc if:true={wrapper} myWrapper={wrapper}></c-second-lwc>
```

I am sure that `myWrapper` is filled because in `html` I can visualise it, but I want to check some fields in the wrapper and based on those values perform some logic.

```
@api myWrapper;
// some logic here based on the values in myWrapper
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Getters and Setters to Modify Data](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_props_getters_setters), `secondLwc.js` would look like:

```
export default class SecondLwc extends LightningElement {
    _myWrapper;

    @api
    get myWrapper() {
        return this._myWrapper;
    }

    set myWrapper(value) {
       // do your processing here with value property
    }

}
```

Worth reading: [Fields, Properties, and Attributes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_props_intro)

Comment: I am putting console logs inside the getters and setters as you said but they're not getting printed

Comment: Kindly share an example illustrating the problem, use https://webcomponents.dev/create/lwc

Comment: Done: https://webcomponents.dev/edit/0TCLVuhRcCg4s8rc3X2P/

Comment: Ah, you should use the setter's `value` parameter to access the property instead of `this._myApplicant`. I adjusted your example: [webcomponents.dev](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/bPCmXNJCyhPkCOgrh5n8)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! now it works